# Alternate GUI toolkits for Tcl

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Other than Tk are there any other toolkits that can be used with Tcl to provide a GUI?

Comment: This isn't Twitter; tags aren't done by putting `#` in front of words…

Comment: @DonalFellows, SO could implement "hashbangtags", I reckon ;-)

Comment: @kostix You want it? Go off and suggest it on meta…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are bindings to [Fltk](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1826), [Gtk](http://wiki.tcl.tk/5151), [Qt](http://wiki.tcl.tk/8188) and [Swing](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2858) (provided you're using [jTcl](http://wiki.tcl.tk/27453)). There used to be a binding to [Motif](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2269) as well if memory serves, but you *really* don't want that!